# Creating spreadsheet from XLS through Google spreadsheet API with PHP and cURL

Tags: php, curl, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create a Spreadsheet from XLS in Google Drive using PHP and cURL. I successfully created Document from .doc, I can create spreadsheet from .csv, but when I'm trying to create a document from xls file, it's just saved in Google Drives as "File", without preview and with option to only download it.

I'm using the following code to initiate the resumable upload:

```
$curl = curl_init();

$upload_href = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full'; // I'm actually taking the upload href from document listing

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$filename = 'MyFile';
$type = 'spreadsheet'; 
$content_type = 'application/msexcel'; // I can use 'text/csv' here to upload csv files     just alright
$body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:docs="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007"><category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#'.$type.'"/><title>'.$filename.'</title></entry>';

$headers = array(
"Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $g_auth, //  using ClientLogin
"GData-Version: 3.0",
"Content-Length: ".strlen($body),
"Content-Type: application/atom+xml",
"X-Upload-Content-Type: ".$content_type,
"X-Upload-Content-Length: ".$buffer_size // the size of the spreadsheet to be uploaded
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_href);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 

$response = curl_exec($curl);

// ...
// what follows is the start of resumable upload
```

Google Spreadsheet API points to Google Docs API on how to create a spreadsheet, but the Google Docs API doesn't point anything specific regarding creating spreadsheets.

I guess the mistake I'm making here is the wrong ContentType, but I have no idea where to look for a valid list of content types Google API accepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried mime type as `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`? It is an acceptable mime type by Google API

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @netcoder Please read the last statement by Ethnar where S/he said s/he has no idea where to look for a valid list of content types that Google API accepts. I simply provided one. If that is not a helpful answer then please insist I remove it. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried using mime application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet and the result is quite odd. The file is uploaded to google docs, but I'm getting message "The spreadsheet at this URL could not be found.". When browsing the files on google drive, I can see the file on the list (as spreadsheet, so that's some success), trying to view it I end up with the same message (not found). I'll check to make sure all the requests are going through properly and that google docs confirms successful file upload. This mime is definitely getting me somewhere, thanks again.

Comment: @Ethnar glad to be of help. Pls share your progress so we all can learn what mistakes not to make later on.

Comment: All the uploads are going through properly, no errors encountered, all reply codes indicate success on every stage. I've found that the "spreadsheet at this URL could not be found" error is very common to people who don't even use API. I found some hints indicating that there's also per-worksheet permissions in google docs and that for some people it caused problems when sharing the work with others. I can't dedicate any more time investigating this issue right now, but I'll be sure to check up on it later and if I happen to find any solution, I'll be sure to write here. Thanks again for help!